# Displaying entries with the same ID from the database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, while-loop

I have a script that allows an admin to view orders that customers have made, where they can decide to view the order details or delete the order. A user can order 1 or more items, for which entries in the database are created with the same order_id, but with different product_id's. When I display my orders these duplicate entries show up, however I only want 1 entry for every order_id. Below is my function

```
function viewOrdersAdmin(){
//This block grabs the orders
$order_list = "";
//Selecting all the orders in the table from that member
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `transactions`") or die(mysql_error());

while ($transactions = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    //creating variables from the information
    $order_id = $transactions["order_id"];
    $mem_id = $transactions["mem_id"];

    $order_details = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `transactionDetails` WHERE `order_id` = $order_id") or die(mysql_error());
    $orderDetailsCount = mysql_num_rows($order_details);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($order_details)) {
        //creating variables from the information
        $order_product_id = $row["Product_ID"];

        $member_details = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `mem_id` = $mem_id") or die(mysql_error());
        $memberDetailsCount = mysql_num_rows($member_details);
        while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($member_details)) {
            //creating variables from the information
            $order_mem_fname = $row2["mem_first_name"];
            $order_mem_lname = $row2["mem_last_name"];

        $order_list .= "Order ID:$order_id - Customer Name: $order_mem_fname $order_mem_lname  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href='manage_order.php?orderid=$order_id'>View</a> &bull; <a href='manage_orders.php?deleteid=$order_id'>Delete</a><br/>";

        }
    }
}

if (count($orderDetailsCount) == 0) {
    $order_list = "You have no orders to display";
}

print_r($order_list);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM transactions
GROUP BY order_id
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't want them to be grouped, I only want to display one from each group

Comment: what about..`SELECT * FROM tablename LIMIT 1`

Comment: But then it only displays the one entry which would be the most recent and not all of the other orders

Comment: What is your expected input and output?

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin I want it to display the order_id so the admin can then choose to view that order. But at the moment it displays this, but when the order contained more than one item, an extra order_id is displayed on this page. Example if order_10 had 2 items, then this page would show the same order_id twice, however I only want it once

Comment: I don't see how that isn't solved by a group by, can you add your desired front end output to your question?

Comment: I Agree, this actually should do exactly what desired.

Comment: It's hard to explain without showing you on my website, but in my database I have order_id and product_id, so an entry can look like order_id = 10, product_id = 7, (new entry but same order) order_id = 11, product_id = 11. So when I use my code above it displays order_id twice, but I only want to display it once, then when admin clicks the order_id, they can view the products from this order

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin Found it, your code works, it just needs to go on the query with `transactionDetails`